# CKfinder & Codeigniter browse server

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have integrated CKEditor/CKFinder into my codeigniter project.

When I click on the image icon, I get the popup. Then when i click on 'browse server' another popup windoe opens containing the original web page. I need this to open a specified folder where I will be saving images to.

I tried editing `$editorObj->config['filebrowserBrowseUrl']` in ckfinder_php5.php but that did not work.
I tried editing `$baseUrl` and `$baseDir` in js/ckfinder/config.php but that did not work either.

What do I need to edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks to [this](http://tutsnare.com/integrate-ckeditor-in-codeigniter/).

In the controller where you are using ckeditor, find `$path = '../js/ckfinder'`
Ensure this is correct, relative to the URL where ckeditor will be used. In my case, I needed to add a folder name, o it looks like this:
`$path = '/folder/js/ckfinder'`